# How to Export a list of lists as it is to File Python

Tags: python

I have the following list of lists:

```
[[25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 0.0], [38.0, 0.0, 1.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0]]
```

I need to export it to a file as text:

```
[[25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 0.0], [38.0, 0.0, 1.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0]]
```

How to do it?

Comment: I'm missing something here... they're the same?

Comment: They are the same, just didn't find samples like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write in a file your list converted to a string:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(your_list))
```